# jQuery effects on AJAXed content delayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a calendar that updates itself using Ajax. This appears to happen nearly instantaneously - it switches from November to December so fast that you can't see the switch. Here's the code that does this - which happens to be included in the page via PHP, so the script lives mid-document. (I did not write this script)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var homegraphurl = '?content_type=plugin&block_id={$block_id}&date=';
    if (document.all) {
        this.homegraphxml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if (!this.homegraphxml && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        try {
            this.homegraphxml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
            this.homegraphxml = false;
        }
    }
    function homegraphcal_load(date) {
        this.homegraphxml.open("GET", homegraphurl + date, true);
        this.homegraphxml.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (homegraphxml.readyState == 4) {
                calElem = document.getElementById('homegraphcal');
                calElem.innerHTML = homegraphxml.responseText;
            }
        };
        this.homegraphxml.send(null);
    }
    homegraphcal_load('2013-12-01');
</script>
```

And then there's another script on the page, which shows up just before the closing body tag, that adds hover Bootstrap popovers to links in the calendar (I did write this script)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on("hover","a.evtday",function(g){
            $(this).popover({
                html: true,
                animation: false,
                trigger: 'hover',
                placement: 'top',
                content: function(){return '<img class="popsmall" src="'+ $(this).data('img') + '" /><br/><span class="winner">Winner: '+ $(this).data('item') + '</span>';}
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that the first time you hover over the link, the popover does not appear. However, it works like a champ after that. What causes this? How can it be solved? I suspect the answer has to do with when the scripts are being called, and in what order, but I'm not sure how to settle this.

Comment: I don't think you can use `on` with `hover`. Hover isn't a real event, it's combination of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: Barbar is right about `.hover` and the delegated form of `.on()` because `.hover` is not a real event that propagates.  Also, your delay may be because an image has to load.  You could try pre-caching an image.

Comment: It doesn't look like `.popover()` displays the popover at the time you call it, it just initializes the plugin. The `trigger:` parameter tells it when to display the popover, so that tells it that it should display the popover the next time you hover over it.

Comment: So I think you should just call `.popover()` outside an event handler, when the document is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use mouseenter event.

Also the problem is when the first mouseenter is done the popover widget is not initialized yet. the solution can be to manually trigger the popover once it is initialized

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "a.evtday", function (g) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('bs.popover')) {
        return;
    }
    $(this).popover({
        html: true,
        animation: false,
        trigger: 'hover',
        placement: 'right',
        content: function () {
            return '<img class="popsmall" src="' + $(this).data('img') + '" /><br/><span class="winner">Winner: ' + $(this).data('item') + '</span>';
        }
    }).popover('show');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jV34P/)

Comment: This works great, thank you very much. However, I'm a little confused about the if statement. What is bs.popover, and where does it come from?

Comment: @L_Holcombe that is to check whether `popover` is already initialized on the element, if it is already initialized then we don't have to call `popover({})` again... `bs.popover` is added the popover plugin